# Submitting iOS app update after 20 September 13 - Xcode 5

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, ios6

I've tried to find an answer by googling around but I haven't found it. On 18 September 2013, Apple will release iOS 7 for compatible devices. After this date to publish an app update or a new app, must I build it using Xcode 5 or can I use Xcode 4.6.2? If I want to use Xcode 4.6.2 to build my application can I use it?

Thanks!

Comment: Apple recommend using the latest version of XCode for development, but because of the significant UI changes that may be needed once you switch to the new SDK, I don't think they will require it for the time being. I believe that yes, you will still be able to use the older version of XCode for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install both Xcode 4x and Xcode 5 on the same machine side by side. It would be better if you test your app on Xcode 5 as soon as possible, because overnight millions of users will shift to iOS 7 and your app might not work at all or work improperly in iOS 7.

Last week when I tried to publish my app from Xcode 4, there was no issue but later I received a email saying 120x120 image is missing which is recommended for iOS 7 users. Hence better if you upgrade to Xcode5 as soon as possible but for now Xcode 4 will definitely work.

Comment: Ok, thanks very much for your answer. I've tried to build my apps using Xcode 5 but there are problems on some views. These problems are not present if I build my apps using Xcode 4.6 and running them on devices with iOS 7. I need to update my apps but I've no time to fix these issues. So I'll try to publish new updates using Xcode 4.6.2. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

After all previous updates, developers were able to use previous versions of XCode and SDK. I think this time will be the same. So don't be worried.